# Symfony 2 Data_collector.time

Tags: symfony, debugging, time

I'm trying to get the load time of my page in Symfony 2 with the associated route/url, i want to log all these information in my database or in a file.

For this i want to use the app_dev.php debug toolbar, where all this information are written but i can't access to them ! I found there are "DataCollector" but nothing else to grab it ...

In Symfony/src/Symfony/bundle/frameworkBundle/ressources/config/collectors.xml i found

```
<service id="data_collector.time" class="%data_collector.time.class%" public="false">
        <tag name="data_collector" template="@WebProfiler/Collector/time.html.twig" id="time" priority="255" />
        <argument type="service" id="kernel" on-invalid="ignore" />
    </service>
```

Can i do smoething with this service ?

I Found another way :

```
$this->container->get('profiler')->get('time');
```

But i have only a starttime not a load time !

Could someone help me about this ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: There's a bunch of info in the docs (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/profiler/data_collector.html) but beyond that I know nothing.

Comment: Yes, i found more info on http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/cookbook/profiler/profiling_data.html but i can't do what i want :(

Comment: yes, the service is declared as private (`public="false"`). try inject the service in a custom service and see if you can reach it. Which version of the framework you use? I think you can use the collector only in the sf dev environment

Comment: I'm using Symfony 2.3, and i can't reach the service using this way :/

Comment: Very strange, running `php app/console container:debug --show-private | grep data_collector` i can't see the time collector. sf 2.3.19

Comment: Me either, only request and router but when i'm trying this : $this->container->get('profiler')->get('time') i've got some info ... My searching send me to the StopWatch component ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could solve this problem in a different way. The required information can be easily obtained in the front controller:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\ApcClassLoader;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../app/bootstrap.php.cache';

require_once __DIR__.'/../app/AppKernel.php';

$start = microtime(true);

$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', false);
$kernel->loadClassCache();

$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);

$finish = microtime(true);
$elapsedTime = $finish - $start;
$uri = $request->getUri();
// ... insert the URI and the elapsed time in the database
```